# Изменение цвета эллипса

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как в Delphi7 изменить цвет эллипса если есть например 5 изображений разных цветом, или это можно организовать по другому (без изображений)?

Comment: Вероятно, перерисовкой.

Comment: а можете примерный код показать, хоть бы для одного элипса

Answer (score 2):

Если вы пользуетесь канвой, то можете для начала почитать [эту статью](http://www.beluch.ru/progr/100comp/4_2.htm). Там все подробно описано:

> "...Канва — объект класса **TCanvas** имеет множество методов, которые позволяют рисовать графики, линии, фигуры с помощью свойства **Pen** — перо. Это свойство является объектом, в свою очередь имеющим ряд свойств. Одно из них уже известное вам свойство **Color** — цвет, которым наносится рисунок. Второе свойство — **Width** (ширина линии). Ширина задается в пикселях..."

А чтобы изменить цвет рисунков, сделанных на канве то их придется заново отрисовать. Для этого вся канва очищается (кажется так, точно не помню :))

```
Canvas.Brush.Color:=clBtnFace; // тут цвет, каким будет зачищена вся выбранная канва
Canvas.FillRect(Canvas.ClipRect);
```

А дальше отрисовываете ваши эллипсы с нужными цветами.

А вообще интернеты выдают много информации по запросу "Delphi canvas"